# Accessing Private ArrayObject - Unsplash API

Tags: php

Hi I am using the Unsplash API to do key word searches. I am using this PHP library to call the API https://packagist.org/packages/unsplash/unsplash

I have written the below code which is returning the image details which is exactly what I need.

```
$search = 'food';
$page = 1;
$per_page = 20;
$orientation = 'landscape';

$thumbnails = UnsplashSearch::photos($search, $page, $per_page, $orientation);

var_dump($thumbnails);
```

This code is returning the following

[image: data]

I am trying to access the reuslts data but it is private which stops me from accessing it.

I am relativelty new to coding so sorry if this isnt an ArrayObject, I just did some research and found this.

How am I able to access the private array? I have read loads of stuff about reflection but it went straight over my head I am presuming Unsplash have a get method allowing me to access it? I can't seem to find it in the documentation though.

I appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: Check out what kind of object that call returns and then check what functions that object's class and baseclass(es) provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Crew\Unsplash\PageResult` class](https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-php/blob/2.5.0/src/PageResult.php#L9)  has several getters, e.g.:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getResults()
{
    return $this->results;
}
```

The class also implements [`\ArrayAccess` interface](https://www.php.net/ArrayAccess) and the corresponding methods operate on the `results` property:

```
public function offsetGet($offset)
{
    return $this->results[$offset];
}
```

... so you have direct access to individual results as well:

```
$thumbnails = UnsplashSearch::photos($search, $page, $per_page, $orientation);
var_dump($thumnails[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much I completely missed the getter methods